# How to change line type, legend label and y and x axis range for multi-line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Yesterday someone on here helped me find a way to plot house price data over time, for a subset of 58 properties I'm looking at. The graph looks great, although I need to tweak it slightly.

**Lines**
I'm wanting to change the lines to black and white, and to differentiate them maybe add dashed lines, dotted lines, etc. They can be various shades of grey, but no colour (it'll be printed in a B&W journal). I know there are heaps of lines, so is it possible to have lines with little triangles in them? It's possible there aren't 58 versions of b&w lines, so maybe I'll need to cut the sample size in half eventually.

**Legend labels**
The other thing I'm wanting to do is update the legend labels so they reflect the property addresses. Does anyone know how to do this?

**Upper tail value on y axis, and more dates on x axis**
Is is also possible to have the upper values shown on the graph? So on my graph that would be $4million or so. And on the X axis, is it possible to have more dates shown? So rather than going up by decades, could it go up by half decades?

Someone called Allan Cameron gave me this code yesterday, and I spent today inputting my own data:

```
data.frame(years, xx, xxx, xxxx, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13,
           col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22, col23, col24,
           col25, col26, col27, col28, col29, col30, col31, col32, col33, col34, col35,
           col36, col37, col38, col39, col40, col41, col42, col43, col44, col45, col46, 
           col47, col48, col49, col50, col51, col52, col53, col54, col55, col56, col57, col58) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-years) %>%
  mutate(is_real = !is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(value = pracma::interp1(years, value, years, "linear")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(years, value, colour = name)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE, linewidth = 2, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(is_real), na.rm = TRUE, size = 4) +
  scale_color_manual("House", values = c("deepskyblue4", "orange", "red", "blue", "purple", 
                                         "lightblue", "pink", "green", "darkorange", "darkred",
                                         "darkgrey", "black", "yellow", "brown", "magenta", "darkgreen", 
                                         "darkblue", "hotpink", "#000033", "#CC0033", "#FF3300", "#CC66FF",
                                         "#999999", "#B70000", "#6A3DC0", "#4E43FB", "#FF0000",
                                         "#00FF22", "#2DFBFB", "#7B6DA0", "#DC448C", "#4F00BE",
                                         "#1F2CFF", "#1FA6FF", "#1FFF9A", "#FF5E1F", "#CCFF1F",
                                         "#C241D9", "#00E2FF", "#26D385", "#B918F3", "#FFC000",
                                         "#FB7B6B", "#900C3F", "#333333", "#40E0D0", "#CCCCFF",
                                         "#FFBF00", "#40E0D0", "#0000FF", "#800080", "#008080",
                                         "#FF2F7F", "#D83B3B", "#F90083", "#0088F9", "#F90000")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, trans = "log10")
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

This has produced the picture attached

[image: Multi-line plot]